# Struts2 action not working with result type both json and dispatcher

Tags: java, ajax, json, jsp, struts2

I have a Struts2 action with result type json. That action gets called from Ajax and a response (an ArrayList) is being received at client side. This is working fine. 
Now, I need to redirect the action to some error page in case of any login error.  So, I tried to include one more result type so that a JSP page can get called. But, it is not working. Please help.

**My Action in Struts.xml**

```
<action name="stocktransferorder" class="com.app.action.StockTransferOrderAction"
            method="createSTO">
            <result name="jsonStockTransferOrderSuccess" type="json" />
            <result name="error" type="dispatcher">/jsp/loginError.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

**My Java Code**

```
String s = (String) session.getAttribute("SAPUSERID");
if (s != null && s.length() > 0) {
        // My code goes here
        return "jsonStockTransferOrderSuccess";

else
        {
            return "error";
        }
}
```

**Getting below lines in console and nothing is happening on the screen**

```
11:38:49,573 DEBUG ServletDispatcherResult:72 - Forwarding to location /jsp/loginError.jsp
11:38:49,573 DEBUG InstantiatingNullHandler:72 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[com.app.action.StockTransferOrderAction@19ae493, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@1dedb45], property=struts]
11:38:49,574 DEBUG InstantiatingNullHandler:72 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[com.app.action.StockTransferOrderAction@19ae493, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@1dedb45], property=org]
11:38:49,607 DEBUG InstantiatingNullHandler:72 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[com.app.action.StockTransferOrderAction@19ae493, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@1dedb45], property=locale]
```

Comment: It is an ajax request. And you want to redirect to other page?

Comment: I am handling AJAX response with the result type JSON. But, in case of error, I need to show some error message on the screen. Is it not possible to redirect to some jsp page?

Comment: With js? Of course you can.

Comment: From Struts.xml? If you pls have a look in my java code, it is returning "error" in case of failure and I want for that failure, a page will open saying a message to the user. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem, looking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of result type="dispatcher" try type="redirect" since you just want to redirect to loginerror page

Comment: Still same.

16:06:15,369 DEBUG ServletRedirectResult:72 - Redirecting to finalLocation /Matix/jsp/loginError.jsp
16:06:15,370 DEBUG InstantiatingNullHandler:72 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[com.app.action.StockTransferOrderAction@112bd54, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@165091f], property=locale]